# How can I use PHP to generate a XML password hash?

Tags: php, xml, xml-rpc

I am planning on using PHP on the client to call an xmlrpc page on a webserver. This will return data to the client via SSL and then I can add relevant information from that data to a database on the client.
How do I encrypt the password used for the server to handshake with the client. Is this even necessary or can I send a plaintext password in the POST as it is using SSL?
If an attacker got onto the client or the server, they could see the password in the PHP files so should I be sending a hashed password instead?

Comment: Send a hashed password.

Comment: @AnotherTest: what would it change?

Comment: Do not use passwords at all, they only offer poor security. Use certificates instead, client side certificates.

Comment: @zerkms if the server is compromised, all data can be read (regardless of SSL). User passwords would not leak if they were hashed on the client side.

Comment: @AnotherTest How do you want to authenticate when you only send a hashed password?!?

Comment: @AnotherTest: so what? If hash allows someone to login - then leaked hash would also allow someone to login. I don't see the difference.

Comment: @zerkms People often use the same password for multiple services. This is a bad thing but it does happen. Assuming a salt the hash is not usable on other services, whereas the password may be.

Comment: @AnotherTest: I'm sure that OP is smart enough to create random password in this case. Especially if the password is not going to be used by human ever. So I still don't see any difference from security perspective :-S

Comment: @zerkms I would say security is better if it does not make any assumptions about how smart the user of the system is. Maybe someone else (who is not so smart) will also use the system, you never know.

Comment: I cannot use certificates as the server is on a host. I can't install anything. The server already has SSL that I can use.

Comment: The best approach here is not hashing, or any particular certificate mechanism, but *signing* - using a secret password to create a value that is only valid for the particular request, and the time it was sent. If both ends know the secret password, they will agree on the signature, but intercepting the signature doesn't allow an attacker to do anything useful.

Comment: you could add the time but the server and client would have to have sycned clocks. The hour or the day?

Comment: @user1898525: just introduce some tolerance and keep clocks in sync. Also google about `nonce`